# Output nested regex groups as nested XML using xsl:analyze-string

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a regex that captures nested groups, and I want to output nested XML that correlates with those groups, just like `fn:analyze-string`. Here's a simple example:

#### Regex

```
((Luckenbach|Houston|Little Rock),\s(TX|AK))
```

#### Input

```
Let's go to Luckenbach, TX with Waylon and Willie and the boys.
```

#### Desired output

```
<s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2009/xpath-functions/analyze-string">
    <s:non-match>Let's go to </s:non-match>
    <s:match>
        <s:group nr="1">
            <s:group nr="2">Luckenbach</s:group>, <s:group nr="3">TX</s:group
        </s:group>
    </s:match>
    <s:non-match> with Waylon and Willie and the boys.</s:non-match>
</s:analyze-string-result>
```

The problem is that it seems like there's no way to recursively process the `regex-group()` values in `xsl:analyze-string` in `xsl:matching-substring` (or access them as XML like the xQuery fn:analyze-string()).

The solution needs to be generic enough to work with different regexes, many which have multiple levels of nested capture groups.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-capturing group for the *outer* group? This way, you wouldn't have nested groups. In other words: `(?:(Luckenbach|Houston|Little Rock),\s(TX|AK))`.

Comment: This is a simplification of a more complicated regex, so unfortunately that wouldn't work for the real problem.

Comment: Also, the flavor of regex used in XPath [doesn't have non-capturing groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#regex-syntax).

Comment: Failure to capture the essence of the real problem and only telling people after they spent considerable time solving the problem, that this question "is a simplification of the actual more complicated regex I'm working with" -- this isn't something to recommend for creating a good question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I think the question was clear, but the desired output did not accurately capture the complexity of the problem. I have updated the output to be more clear. My apologies to Mads Hansen for any time lost working on this.

Comment: @wst, I think that it is sensible to accept Mads' answer and to ask a new question -- this time better.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I appreciate his effort, but Mads was unable to solve the problem without modifying the regex, and his updated answer was also fundamentally different from `analyze-sting()`'s behavior. They also did not address the problem of recursively processing `regex-group()`s. I don't see how it's sensible to accept an incorrect answer. If the SO community votes to close, that's fine, but I think the question is clear as is.

Answer (score 2):

The following produces the desired output when the context node contains the example text:

```
    <snip>
        <xsl:analyze-string 
                select="." 
                regex="((Luckenbach|Houston|Little Rock),\s(TX|AK))">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <location>
                    <city><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></city>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <state><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></state>
                </location>                       
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>    
    </snip>
```

If you wanted to only produce the `<snip>` if the REGEX matched, you could adjust the REGEX and processing of groups slightly:

```
        <xsl:analyze-string 
                select="." 
                regex="((.*)((Luckenbach|Houston|Little Rock),\s(TX|AK))(.*))">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <snip>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                    <location>
                        <city><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></city>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <state><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(5)"/></state>
                    </location>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(6)"/>
                </snip>   
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
```

---

If you want to reproduce the behavior of the XQuery function [analyze-string()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-analyze-string), you could define your own custom function:

```
<xsl:function name="my:analyze-string" as="item()*" xmlns:my="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187307/output-nested-regex-groups-as-nested-xml-using-xslanalyze-string">
    <xsl:param name="val" />

    <analyze-string-result xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">   
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$val" regex="((.*)((Luckenbach|Houston|Little Rock),\s(TX|AK))(.*))">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to 6">
                    <xsl:if test="regex-group(.)">
                        <match>
                            <group  nr="{.}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(.)"/>
                            </group>
                        </match>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <non-match>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </non-match> 
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>    
    </analyze-string-result>   
</xsl:function>
```

When invoked like this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="value" 
      select='"Let&apos;s go to Luckenbach, TX with Waylon and Willie and the boys."'/>
 <xsl:copy-of select="my:analyze-string($value)"
    xmlns:my="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187307/output-nested-regex-groups-as-nested-xml-using-xslanalyze-string"/>
```

It produces the following output:

```
<analyze-string-result xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                       xmlns:my="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187307/output-nested-regex-groups-as-nested-xml-using-xslanalyze-string">
   <match>
      <group nr="1">Let's go to Luckenbach, TX with Waylon and Willie and the boys.</group>
   </match>
   <match>
      <group nr="2">Let's go to </group>
   </match>
   <match>
      <group nr="3">Luckenbach, TX</group>
   </match>
   <match>
      <group nr="4">Luckenbach</group>
   </match>
   <match>
      <group nr="5">TX</group>
   </match>
   <match>
      <group nr="6"> with Waylon and Willie and the boys.</group>
   </match>
</analyze-string-result>
```

Comment: Mads, thank you for the suggestion, but the example I provided is a simplification of the actual more complicated regex I'm working with. It contains some optional and repeating groups that can't really be handled this way. I am looking for a more generic solution. Please see the xQuery 3.0 implementation of fn:analyze-string() for an idea of what I'm looking for -- It simply might not be possible in XSL.
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-analyze-string

Comment: I'm pretty sure that anything that can be done using fn:analyze-string can also be done using xsl:analyze-string, if only because Saxon uses the same underlying code for both. Unfortunately we're in "this is a simplified version of my problem" mode, which makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: I apologize if you think I made this a more difficult - I was only trying to save folks from getting bogged down in implementation specific details. But this is what the `fn:analyze-string()` output looks like:

`<s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2009/xpath-functions/analyze-string">
    <s:non-match>Let's go to </s:non-match>
    <s:match>
        <s:group nr="1"><s:group nr="2">Luckenbach</s:group>, <s:group nr="3">TX</s:group></s:group>
    </s:match>
    <s:non-match> with Waylon and Willie and the boys.</s:non-match>
</s:analyze-string-result>`